# Laravel Livewire wire:click() deleting component property?

Tags: components, laravel-livewire

Hi fellow stackoverflowers,
I am running repeatedly into following issue while digging myself into Laravel8 Livewire capabilities. In my Livewire component called Ticker I am reading a series of dates data from a calendar table into a component property `$days`.

In my view I am displaying a div element for each element of `$days` with a `wire:click`, which should wire to the component's tick() method.
The view renders and mounts fine, but each time an element is clicked, a `"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object $day->id"` error appears - as if the `$days` property had been deleted or emptied by the method call. Can anyone help me in understanding this behaviour?

Component Ticker.php:

```
class Counter extends Component
{
   public $days;

   public function mount()
   {
       $this->days = \DB::table("caldays")->WhereBetween("id", [320, 326])->get();
   }

   public function render()
   {
       return view('livewire.ticker');
   }

   public function tick($id)
   {
       /* do stuff with selected $id */
   }
}
```

View ticker.blade.php:

```
...
@foreach($days as $day)
    <div class="border border-light-blue-500 border-opacity-75 p-6 text-center"
         wire:click="tick({{ $day->id }})"
    >
@endforeach
...
```

Many thx in advance & happy year & stay healthy!

Comment: 1. Why are you not using models? 2. The code for the `tick()` method is relevant, including it could help.

Comment: Hi Qirel, 1. Maybe I'm wrong but I understand that models are for use with input elements only which we don't have in this case. How would you do that? 2. For testing I have tried most different code bits in the method including just assigning the parameter to a variable or leave the method body entirely blank. Always the same error.

Comment: A model is just a representation of a given thing. For example a database record. So it would make sense to have a model here, rather than using the DB facade. You also have to use `wire:key` when looping. It would also help to know which line the error occurs at.

Comment: You were just right with your suggestion! I have changed `$this->days = \DB::table("caldays")->WhereBetween...` to `$this->days = Calday::WhereBetween...` and the non-object errors stopped appearing. Thank you! I still don't understand thou what makes the difference in the component behaviour with Eloquent and Query Builder collections.

Answer (score -1):

You have to notice that. After delete your respective day this will not update your collection anyway. So after deletion you have to re query the days.Or Simply remove the respective day from your collection.
Try This:

```
@forelse($days as $day)
    <div class="border border-light-blue-500 border-opacity-75 p-6 text-center"
         wire:click="tick({{ $day->id }})"
    >
@empty
    <p>No day found</p>
@endforelse
```

Another solution is:

```
@if(count($days>0)
    @foreach($days as $day)
        <div class="border border-light-blue-500 border-opacity-75 p-6 text-center"
             wire:click="tick({{ $day->id }})"
        >
    @endforeach
@endif
```

In php file:

```
public function tick($dayId){
    $day = \DB::table("caldays")->Where("id", $dayId)->get();
    $day->delete();
    if(in_array($dayId,$this->days)) {
        $key = array_search($dayId, $this->days);
        array_splice($this->days, $key, 1);
     }
}
```

Comment: This would not make any difference, quite the contrary it doesn't quite make sense to convert the collection to an array.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the description properly. If you have only one row in the collection and you have delete the this you will have an empty collection that drives the $day->id to find the id of a non object.

Comment: If the collection is empty, then it won't be iterated in the loop -- and even if you converted it to an array, by your logic, you would still get "*Trying to get offset "id" of string/null*" or similar error message. So neither of these updated answers would change anything, since it won't be looped in any case.

Comment: Yes you are right. But those are to just rechecks. The problem was with if I delete the entry it will not update the collection. And again it loops over same data collection but this time If I want to delete the data that is already deleted . It will throw the error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object $day->id". I hope this is the reason.